# Comparing the value of a Character to those in a Character Array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, char

I have an array of characters. I am searching for a pattern of consonant then vowel then consonant for several user input words in my code, even though I just have one in this example. Is there a way to see if a character in the string matches any character in an array. Is there a better way to look at the problem? I know I could list out all the possibilities in the if statement but I'm looking for a faster method.

```
    char[] carray= new char[] {'t','z','r','v'};
     char[] varray= new char[] {'t','z','r','v'};
 String stringy = "rival"; 
`for( int n=0;n<= stringy.length-2;n++){
if(stringy.charAt(n)== "any character in carray" && stringy.charAt(n+1)=="any character in varray" && stringy.charAt(n+2)=="any char in carray" ) {
//code
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're "looking for a faster method" to "search for a pattern of consonant then vowel then consonant", forget arrays and use regex:

```
if (stringy.matches(".*(?i)[^aeiou][aeiou][^aeiou].*")) {
    // string contains pattern of consonant then vowel then consonant
}
```

Regex engines are pretty fast, because they implemented by building a state machine for the pattern. There isn't a faster executing way to achieve what you want.

Writing code is also faster, because there's a lot less code to write.

---

If you have a collection of user input strings, to find all that match your target pattern:

```
List<String> userInputStrings;

List<String> matchingStrings = userInputStrings.stream()
    .filter(str -> str.matches(".*(?i)[^aeiou][aeiou][^aeiou].*"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```